# Setting default tolerance on Global Planner with Move Base

Tags: ros, navigation, base-global-planner, husky, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I am trying to set the default tolerance on the GlobalPlanner using move_base for a simulation I am doing with a husky. The key behavior I am looking for is that if I give the husky a goal that is in a known obstacle, it will use the default tolerance parameter to replan to a point that is not in an obstacle. I had success in this endeavor using NavfnROS as the planner and setting the default tolerance, but the behavior of NavfnROS is not what I want, it's very unreliable and the husky often stops 4 or 5 times along the way to a goal.

My problem is that when I set the default_tolerance parameter using the GlobalPlanner (using the same method I used to set it with the NavfnROS) is that the planner won't find a valid plan if I set a goal in an obstacle. I have included below  the launch file I am using, with the portion of interest being the move_base launch include, as well as the .yaml file I am using to specify the parameters I want to use.

launch file portion:

```
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">

<param name="base_global_planner" value="$(arg base_global_planner)"/>
<rosparam file="$(find husky_nav)/config/global_planner.yaml" command="load"/>
<param name="base_local_planner" value="$(arg base_local_planner)"/>  
<rosparam file="$(find husky_nav)/config/draper_local_planner.yaml" command="load"/>

<!-- observation sources located in costmap_common.yaml -->
<rosparam file="$(find husky_nav)/config/costmap_common.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find husky_nav)/config/costmap_common.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />

<param name="global_costmap/robot_base_frame" value = "$(arg tf_prefix)/base_link" if="$(arg use_tf_prefix)"/>
<param name="global_costmap/robot_base_frame" value = "base_link" unless="$(arg use_tf_prefix)"/>

<param name="local_costmap/robot_base_frame" value = "$(arg tf_prefix)/base_link" if="$(arg use_tf_prefix)"/>
<param name="local_costmap/robot_base_frame" value = "base_link" unless="$(arg use_tf_prefix)"/>

<!-- local costmap, needs size -->
<rosparam file="$(find husky_nav)/config/costmap_local.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
<param name="local_costmap/width" value="10.0"/>
<param name="local_costmap/height" value="10.0"/>
<param name="local_costmap/global_frame" value="/map"/>

<!-- static global costmap, static map provides size -->
<rosparam file="$(find husky_navigation)/config/costmap_global_static.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" unless="$(arg no_static_map)"/>

<!-- global costmap with laser, from odom_navigation_demo -->
<rosparam file="$(find husky_nav)/config/costmap_global_laser.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" if="$(arg no_static_map)"/>
<param name="global_costmap/width" value="100.0" if="$(arg no_static_map)"/>
<param name="global_costmap/height" value="100.0" if="$(arg no_static_map)"/>
<param name="global_costmap/global_frame" value="/map"/>
```

global_planner.yaml file
GlobalPlanner:
default_tolerance: 0.5

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239236/setting-default-tolerance-on-global-planner-with-move-base/) by [emielke](https://answers.ros.org/users/27456/emielke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 261 on 2016-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I looked up the global planner source code in the GitHub and I found the problem.

I checked the default_tolerance parameter in the code. As you can see there is a default_tolerance_ parameter which is read from parameter server.

```
    private_nh.param("default_tolerance", default_tolerance_, 0.0);
```

Afterwards I looked up the usages of this parameter. There's only a single line that uses this parameter:

```
    return makePlan(start, goal, default_tolerance_, plan);
```

I dug further in ...

```
    bool GlobalPlanner::makePlan(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start, const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal, double tolerance, std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan)
```

Unfortunately the tolerance parameter in makePlan doesn't have any usages at all. which means changing this parameter won't change the behavior of the global planner.

I didn't fully check your parameters but they seem fine. I think with a little modification in the global planner source code you'll get the result you want.

---

Originally posted by [Arwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10946/arwen/) with karma: 146 on 2016-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [emielke](https://answers.ros.org/users/27456/emielke/) on 2016-07-13**:
Perfect! I was hoping I would be able to solve this without any alterations, but it looks like I will. Thanks!

**Comment by [Arwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10946/arwen/) on 2016-07-13**:
Anytime.
Just let me know if you needed more help.

**Comment by [juanlu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29661/juanlu/) on 2017-04-27**:
Hey, did you finally implement this? Im in need of the same thing.

**Comment by [emielke](https://answers.ros.org/users/27456/emielke/) on 2017-04-27**:
Yes I did, I ended up having to write my own algorithm in global_planner to basically backtrack the goal point any time it was in an obstacle. I don't have enough room here or points ot reopen the question, if you want you could open a new question and I could answer it.

**Comment by [juanlu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29661/juanlu/) on 2017-04-27**:
I did [exactly that](http://answers.ros.org/question/260482/move-base-default-tolerance/)